# Numerical Programming - Matlab and R give different values

Tags: r, matlab

I'm trying to compute the PCA scores, and, part of the algorithm says: `subtract the mean of the matrix, divided by the standard deviation`

I have the following 2x2 matrix given by: `A = [1 3; 2 4]` let's say in Matlab, I do the following:

`mean(A)` -> This gives me back a vector of 2 values (column based) so.. 1.5 and 3.5. Which to me in this instance this would be correct.

In R however, when computing the mean `mean(A)` the mean is just one value. This is the same for the standard deviation.

So my question is, which is right? For the purposes of this function (in the algorithm):

`function(x) {(x - mean(x))/sd(x)` (http://strata.uga.edu/software/pdf/pcaTutorial.pdf)

Should I be subtracting the mean based on two values by Matlab or 1 value by R?

Thanks

Comment: Have a look at the `colMeans` function in R. There is no `colSDs` (though you could define one easily), but you can use `apply` for calculating colwise SDs.

Comment: From where did you get "subtract the mean of the matrix, divided by the standard deviation"? The context should explain if the mean (single value) or the mean among a dimension is intended. I assume it's a single value, because otherwise the algorithm would have to specify the dimension. To do this in matlab, use `mean(A(:))`

Comment: @Daniel Centering for PCA is done for each variable (i.e., column of the data matrix).

Comment: @Daniel Please see here: http://strata.uga.edu/software/pdf/pcaTutorial.pdf page 5.. I'm calculating the long way as I'm trying create an algorithm for calculating the means and this seems the only useful resource out there

Answer (score 2):

The R command that will do this in one swoop for matrices or dataframes is `scale()`

```
> A = matrix(c(1, 3, 2, 4), 2)
> scale(A)
           [,1]       [,2]
[1,] -0.7071068 -0.7071068
[2,]  0.7071068  0.7071068
attr(,"scaled:center")
[1] 2 3
attr(,"scaled:scale")
[1] 1.414214 1.414214
```

It's done by column. When you used 'mean' you got the mean for all four numbers rather than by column. That is *not* what you would want if you are doing PCA calculations.

Comment: @BoundedDust - So when you carry out PCA calculations, you take the mean of all four numbers and NOT the columns, what I was originally doing?

Comment: No, just the opposite. When doing PCA you scale each variable. The naive way would be `apply(A, 2, mean)`

Comment: Let me just get this right... Let's say you have a matrix: $A = [1, 2; 3, 4]` You would calculate the mean: `2 3` and SD: `1.4142    1.4142` and then you would do the following: `1 - 2/sd`, `2-3`, `3-2`, `4-3` so this is correct? Sorry I think I'm understanding what you mean now.. Thanks, but I might be wrong so can you confirm?

Comment: You are talking to a non-Matlab user. Assuming that Matlab handles its matrices in column-major order (which is how R defines its matrices) then the means would be 1.5 and 3.5. If Matlab handles its matrices in row major order then you would need to add a `byrow=TRUE` to the `matrix` call above that defines `A` in order to be at the same starting point for this discussion.